# IE Debugger inaccessible

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I am trying to simulate **showModalDialog** behavior with **window.open** function.

To block access to parent window, I used a **while loop** :

```
while(resultPopup && !resultPopup.closed){
        resultPopup.focus();
}
```

This, technically works fine, make parent window unreachable but whenever I try to debug the popup in IE, the focus stays on the popup and the debugger became unreachable too.

Is there anyway to make IE Debugging Tool reachable with JavaScript?

Comment: Create a fixed cover on the top of the main page, then listen `focusin` event of the cover. In the handler, return the focus back to pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

That creates an endless loop and there is no chance for the browser to `breath` -- to refresh or do anything.

I can't test it, but if anything will work, it would be something like this:

```
// Raw, untested code
function tryIt() {
    if (resultPopup && !resultPopup.closed){
        setTimeout(function()  {
            resultPopup.focus();
            console.log("Retrying...");
            tryIt();
        }, 10);
    }
}
```